# XCEED ListBox : remove selected item from collection MVVM Pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, xceed

The XCEED ListBox does not exist `SelectedIndex` property for pass index of selection to `ViewModel`, How can remove selected item without breaking MVVM, I think XCEED ListBox is not fully supported MVVM pattern, What is your opinion?